# how sling script resolution works in adobe day cq

Tags: adobe, aem

i am using adobe cq5.5. I could not understand how sling resolution works in cq5.5

Could someone please explain how sling works in cq with example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This link will give you all the details:

https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/the_basics.html

Pay close attention to the graphic titled "Understanding Apache Sling Script Resolution" and the section "From URL to Content and Scripts."

This information is also useful: http://sling.apache.org/site/documentation.html

Comment: More precisely, http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/url-to-script-resolution.html explains how URLs are mapped to scripts and servlets.